# Aggregation and Sorting in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe below. I want to order them and take top 10 and bottom 10. I am using below code.

```
 d={
        'product_category_name_english' :['food','drinks','housewares','small_appliances','construction_tools_lights'],
        'Median':[7.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0],
        'Count':[620, 560, 924, 2035, 308]
    }
    
df=pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Category','Median','Count'])
```

Using Code:

```
df_top10 = df.sort_values('Median',ascending=True).head(10)
df_bottom10 = df.sort_values('Median',ascending=False).head(10)
```

But, finally I want to do like this:

How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understand you can concat then on axis=1 with keys`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df_top10 = df.sort_values('Median',ascending=True).head(10)
df_bottom10 = df.sort_values('Median',ascending=False).head(10)

out = (pd.concat((df_top10.reset_index(drop=True),df_bottom10.reset_index(drop=True))
       ,axis=1,keys=['Top10','Bottom10']))
```

---

```
     Top10                                   Bottom10  \
  product_category_name_english Median Count product_category_name_english   
0                          food    7.0   620                    housewares   
1                        drinks    7.0   560              small_appliances   
2                    housewares    8.0   924     construction_tools_lights   
3              small_appliances    8.0  2035                          food   
4     construction_tools_lights    8.0   308                        drinks   

                
  Median Count  
0    8.0   924  
1    8.0  2035  
2    8.0   308  
3    7.0   620  
4    7.0   560
```